# Change the speed of brightness being set

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently I am using the following method to change the brightness

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
float brightness = 1.0f;
lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

This changes the brightness of the activity from the current brightness to full brightness. This happens gradually, Is it possible to change the speed of the brightness being set? I want to increase the speed of brightness being set.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @MeetBhavsar This changes the brightness of the device itself, I just want it for an activity, additionally it requires write permission for it to work, which I do not want to prompt as it ruins user experience.

Answer (score -1):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
int progress = 100;
Settings.System.putInt(this,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progress);
```

Comment: As he stated in comments, he wants to change it just for this activity, not for the device.

Comment: i thing so it not possible

Comment: The above code I wrote. changes the brightness of the screen for the current activity. The only issue I have is that it changes very slowly, I want it to change the speed of brightness being changed.